# Video Rental in C

Tags: c, database, data-structures, file-io, dynamic-arrays

I am a newbie in programming because I started studying Computer Science.
I have a task to make a program using C  language.
I am working on it but I am facing a problem in my most significant function: insert_a_new_movie.
More specifically , when I compile and insert information , it stops at the last insertion (year) and returns status != 0...

**** WHAT THE TASK IS ABOUT ****
You are called to implement a program in C language which
will simulate the operation of a movie management information system for
Video Club.
More specifically, your program should offer the following features:

- Insert a new movie
- Delete movie by id
- Search  movie by title
- Search for a movie based on a director's surname
  Information describing a movie will be stored in a text file (.txt)
  The text file will be read at the start of the program and the recordings set
  contains will be uploaded to a movie dynamic array.
  You have to work with structures (using typedef).

//The structures I have to use , you can find them in the code I attach below.
The movie code(id )should be calculated and given automatically by the program.

The new insertion will be stored at the end of the table.

The user should be able to repeatedly select one of the above actions
until he enters the number 5, at which point the program will end.

In this case, the file that holds the movie information should be written off
overwrite so that if a record is entered or deleted
to keep the changes made by the user.
CODE I HAVE WRITEN TILL NOW

```
     #include <stdio.h
     #include <stdlib.h
     #include <string.h>
     #define SIZE 100



        typedef struct date
        {
                  int day,month,year;   

        }date;

        typedef struct director_info
        {
           char director_name[SIZE];
           char director_surname[SIZE];
        }director_info;

        typedef struct movie 
         {
             int id;
           char title[SIZE];

            director_info *director;



            date *release_date;

            }movie;

            typedef struct movies
            {
                 movie *array;
                 int capacity;
                  int size;

             }movies;
            

                  
            int menu();
            void insert_a_new_movie(movies *mo);
            void save_movie_to_a_file(movies *mo,char *filename);
            void load_movies_from_file(movies *mo,char *filename);


            int main(int argc,char *argv[])


  {

int choice,pos;
movies mo;
char filename[SIZE];
int counter=0;  

choice=menu();
while(choice)
{
    if(choice==1)
    {
        //1.insert a new movie.--->Check first time or load a file.
        
        insert_a_new_movie(&mo);
            
    }
    else if(choice==2)
    {
        //2.delete a movie based on movies' id.
        
        
    }
    else if(choice==3)
    {
        //3.search a movie based on the title.
        
    }
    else if(choice==4)
    {
        //4.search a movie based on surname of the director.
        
    }
    else if(choice==5)
    {
        //5.exit --->While exiting ,program should be saved on a file.  
        printf("Before exiting make sure you will save the file.\n");
        printf("FILENAME:");
        scanf("%s",filename);
        save_movie_to_a_file(&mo,filename);
        
        printf("\nMOVIE(-S) SAVED!\n");
        return 0;
        
    }
    
    choice=menu();
}
return 0;   
    
}



int menu()


       {
        int choice;
        printf("************* VIDEO CLUB  ****************\n");
        printf("1. INSERT A NEW MOVIE.\n");
        printf("2. DELETE A MOVIE BY GIVING ID.\n");
        printf("3. SEARCH A MOVIE BY GIVING THE TITLE.\n");
        printf("4. SEARCH A MOVIE BY GIVING DIRECTOR'S SURNAME.\n");
        printf("5. EXIT PROGRAM.\n");

        scanf("%d",&choice);

        return choice;

     }

     void insert_a_new_movie(movies *mo)
    {

int counter=1;

movie m;
m.id=counter++;

printf("Please give information about the movie.\n");
printf("MOVIE'S ID : %d\n",m.id);



printf("TITLE:  \n");
fflush(stdin);
scanf("%s",m.title);

printf("DIRECTOR'S SURNAME: \n");
fflush(stdin);
scanf("%s",m.director->director_surname);

printf("DIRECTOR'S NAME: \n");
fflush(stdin);
scanf("%s",m.director->director_name);

printf("RELEASE DAY: \n");
fflush(stdin);
scanf("%d",&m.release_date->day);


printf("RELEASE MONTH: \n");
fflush(stdin);
scanf("%d",&m.release_date->month);

printf("RELEASE YEAR: \n");
fflush(stdin);
scanf("%d",&m.release_date->year);

if(mo->size >= mo->capacity)
{
    mo->capacity +=10;
    mo->array=realloc(mo->array,sizeof(movie)* mo->capacity);
    
}

strcpy(mo->array[mo->size].title,m.title);
strcpy(mo->array[mo->size].director->director_surname,m.director->director_surname);
strcpy(mo->array[mo->size].director->director_name,m.director->director_name);
mo->array[mo->size].release_date->day=m.release_date->day;
mo->array[mo->size].release_date->month=m.release_date->month;  
mo->array[mo->size].release_date->year=m.release_date->year;


mo->size++;
m.id-=counter++;

}

          void save_movie_to_a_file(movies *mo,char *filename)
{
int i;
FILE *fp;

if((fp=fopen(filename,"w"))==NULL)
{
    fprintf(stderr, "ERROR.\n");
    return; 
}

for(i=0;i<mo->size;i++)
{
    fprintf(fp,"%s",mo->array[i].title);
    fprintf(fp,"%s",mo->array[i].director->director_surname);
    fprintf(fp,"%s",mo->array[i].director->director_name);
    fprintf(fp,"%d",mo->array[i].release_date->day);
    fprintf(fp,"%d",mo->array[i].release_date->month);
    fprintf(fp,"%d",mo->array[i].release_date->year);
}
 
 fclose(fp);
    
 }

  void load_movies_from_file(movies *mo,char *filename)
 {
int i;
char line[100];
char *tok;
FILE *fp;
if ((fp=fopen(filename,"r"))==NULL)
{
fprintf(stderr,"FILE NOT FOUND.\n");
return; 
}
while(!feof(fp))
{
fgets(line,100,fp);
tok=strtok(line,"\n\0");

if(mo->size >= mo->capacity)
{
    mo->capacity +=10;
     mo->array=realloc(mo->array,sizeof(movie)*mo->capacity);   
}

if (tok != NULL) 
{
          strcpy(mo->array[mo->size].title,tok);
          tok = strtok(NULL, " \n\0");
                
          if (tok != NULL) 
    {
                strcpy(mo->array[mo->size].director->director_surname,tok);
                tok = strtok(NULL, " \n\0");
                    if (tok != NULL) 
              {
                        strcpy(mo->array[mo->size].director->director_name,tok);
                        tok = strtok(NULL, " \n\0");
                        
                        if(tok!=NULL)
                        {
                                mo->array[mo->size].release_date->day = atoi(tok);
                    tok = strtok(NULL, " \n\0");
                    
                    if(tok!=NULL)
                                {
                                    mo->array[mo->size].release_date->month = atoi(tok);
                        tok = strtok(NULL, " \n\0");
                        
                        if(tok!=NULL)
                                    {
                                        mo->array[mo->size].release_date->year = atoi(tok);
                            tok = strtok(NULL, " \n\0");
                            }
                        }
                  }
                  }
                }
    }

   mo->size++;

}
fclose(fp);
```

}

So, can anyone help me out to find what is happening at the insertion function (1.)?
And any opinion about the solution is welcomed.

Thank you a lot!

Comment: "it stops at the last insertion (year) and returns status != 0". What does that mean? The `insert_a_new_movie` function doesn't return anything and what does "stops" mean. Also, debugging question on Stack Overflow should not be a full code dump but rather a [minimal verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example). That is, code should be reduced to the minimal complete code that can reproduce the problem.

Comment: Please use proper indentation for your code.

Answer (score 0):

You are not allocating storage for any of your structures. I partially rewrote your `insert_a_new_movie` function. It still doesn't fully work, but it is a start. Note the calls to `malloc`. Read up on [this](https://www.freecodecamp.org/news/the-c-beginners-handbook/), and relevant chapters of [this book](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_C_Programming_Language). Also, make sure to compile your code as `gcc -g -Wall video_rental.c`, [so that you can use `gdb`](http://www.cs.cmu.edu/%7Egilpin/tutorial/) and see all the warnings.

```
void insert_a_new_movie(movies *mo)
{

    int counter=1;

    movie *m = malloc(sizeof *m);

    m->director = malloc(sizeof(director_info));
    m->id = counter++;
    m->release_date = malloc(sizeof(date));

    printf("Please give information about the movie.\n");
    printf("MOVIE'S ID : %d\n",m->id);



    printf("TITLE:  \n");
    fflush(stdin);
    scanf("%s",m->title);

    printf("DIRECTOR'S SURNAME: \n");
    fflush(stdin);
    scanf("%s",m->director->director_surname);

    printf("DIRECTOR'S NAME: \n");
    fflush(stdin);
    scanf("%s",m->director->director_name);

    printf("RELEASE DAY: \n");
    fflush(stdin);
    scanf("%d",&(m->release_date->day));


    printf("RELEASE MONTH: \n");
    fflush(stdin);
    scanf("%d",&(m->release_date->month));

    printf("RELEASE YEAR: \n");
    fflush(stdin);
    scanf("%d",&(m->release_date->year));

    if(mo->size >= mo->capacity)
    {
        mo->capacity +=10;
        mo->array=realloc(mo->array,sizeof(movie)* mo->capacity);

    }

    strcpy(mo->array[mo->size].title,m->title);
    strcpy(mo->array[mo->size].director->director_surname,m->director->director_surname);
    strcpy(mo->array[mo->size].director->director_name,m->director->director_name);
    mo->array[mo->size].release_date->day=m->release_date->day;
    mo->array[mo->size].release_date->month=m->release_date->month;  
    mo->array[mo->size].release_date->year=m->release_date->year;


    mo->size++;
    m->id-=counter++;

}
```